# Which kinds of survival equipment does Crew Dragon have, in case of an emergency landing?

Tags: landing, dragon-v2, emergency

Soyuz spacecraft has various survival equipment for different cases of emergency landing.

The cases include water landing, desert landing, snow winter landing (crews have special winter suits). They also used to have pistols/handguns for self-defence.

What about Crew Dragon?

**Is information available regarding what survival equipment Crew Dragon has for NASA flights?** (For non-NASA flights like Inspiration4 the list would be the same or less, I think).

Is the complete list available for public access?

For example I doubt Crew Dragon has winter suits, because it lands on water.